# instagram feed error is coming in server in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, plugin

when I am using widget it is giving an error like
We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.
and the error is in this code
Instagram.phtml

```
<?php
  $helper = $this->helper('\Solwin\Instagram\Helper\Data');
  $enable = $helper- 
 >getConfig('instagramsection/instagramgroup/active');
 $userId = $helper- 
 >getConfig('instagramsection/instagramgroup/userid');
 $accessToken = $helper- 
>getConfig('instagramsection/instagramgroup/accesstoken');
 $imageNumber = $this->getData('numberimage');
$imageResolution = $this->getData('resolution');
 ?>

<?php
 if ($enable) {
  ?>
<div class="block-title-main">
    <h2><?php echo $this->getData('title'); ?></h2>
    <div class="title-border"></div>
</div>
<div id="cpcolumninstagram" class="cp-fcontent hidden-xs">
    <?php
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $userId . '/media/recent/?access_token=' . $accessToken.'&count='.$imageNumber;
    $args = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 2500,)));
    //for Live server

    $instagramFeedsData = file_get_contents($url, false, $args);
    // for Local Server
    // $instagramFeedsData = $helper->getInstangramData($url);


    $instagramFeeds = json_decode($instagramFeedsData);

    $instangramData = $instagramFeeds->data;
    foreach ($instangramData as $instagramFeed) {
        $instagramImage = $instagramFeed->images->$imageResolution->url;
        ?>

        <?php
        $caption_text = 'Instagram';
        if (is_object($instagramFeed->caption)) {
            $caption_text = $instagramFeed->caption->text;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="instangram-feed">
            <a href ="<?php echo $instagramFeed->link; ?>" target="_blank">
                <img src="<?php echo $instagramImage; ?>" title="<?php echo $caption_text; ?>" alt="<?php echo $caption_text; ?>"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    } ?>
</div>
<div class="clear gap-30"></div>
<?php }
```

i am not getting where is the error in this

Comment: HI ,Mr.Ashish Ramchandani

Have you found the solution for this , if you   have any idea please share me 
iam also facing same issue
thanks in advance...

Comment: yes you have to generate the user id of that particular account by using https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-user-id link and enter that user id in admin@ChalaChalapathi

Comment: Thanks a lot @ashish Ramchandani

Comment: Facebook introduced new GraphAPI so old user id and authentication token may not work anymore to fetch the instagram images.
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-instagram-integration-pro.html